# Displaying a Value while linking a Key with the Linked Field Module

Tags: entities, navigation

I am using the [linked field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/linked_field) to try to display a particular field as a link on a content page (I am not working within a View).  The field is a select list with associated urls in the key.  For example, the Value "Accounting Department" may have a key of "/drupal/accounting".  I want the link to show "Accounting Department" but map the link to what is in the key.  If I map to the field with this module, it tries to go to "/drupal/Accounting Department".  Has anyone else attempted something like this or is there another module that will allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the "token" view mode for the content type in question.

First, ensure you're set up to configure the "tokens" view mode separately from your other view modes.

1. Click to go to the "default" view mode:
   [image]
2. Near the bottom, click "Custom display settings" and check "tokens", then save.
   [image]
3. Now you will see "Tokens" in your list of view modes to configure:
   [image]

Go to that page, find the field that contains the key you want and, in the drop-down in the format column, change it to "key".

Comment: Tried that. If I change it to "Key", it does link in the proper page but the link then displays the key as well.  So in this case, it visibly shows "/drupal/accounting".  Is it supposed to have a different behavior?

Comment: @BigEMPin It does that even if you have the format on the "Full Content" view mode for that field set to "default" (not "key")?

Comment: If it is set to the default, it does the exact opposite.  It will display the value, but will also link to the value instead of the key.

Comment: What view mode are you trying to get this to work for?  You need to set your view modes such that you can configure your "tokens" view mode separately from your "full content" view mode.

Comment: @BigEMPin I've updated my answer to show you how to configure the view mode for tokens separately from the default view mode.

Comment: OK I've finally got a chance to get back to this, I'm getting the same behavior after this is configured.  Is there a certain way that I need to get the link set up?  It will still only allow the value of the field to be set as the link destination.

Comment: @BigEMPin Can you please post a screenshot of how you have the link options for the field formatter configured?

Comment: Cancel that...figured it out.  I was setting the link assignment in the wrong place and had to use the Text attribute to display the different data.  Everything is good to go.  Thanks for your help.